# QRCodeReader.swift toggleTorchButton selected image dont work

Tags: swift, uibutton, qr-code, selected

I'm using QRCodeReader.swift and the possibility to change layout is good, but the selected option of button don't work.

```
toggleTorchButton?.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_light_on"), for: .normal)
toggleTorchButton?.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_light_off"), for: .selected)
```

If I test the `.highlighted` state this works fine, but `.selected` never.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm create a target and this change the selected state.

```
toggleTorchButton?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.toggleTorchButtonHandler), for: .touchUpInside)

func toggleTorchButtonHandler() {
    toggleTorchButton?.isSelected = !(toggleTorchButton?.isSelected)!
}
```